# Pandas: Check if a substring exists in another column then create a new column with a specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```py
Receipt Description Card Member Account Cost
200a apple adam 08203928 $2
20022a pear bob 08203228 $7
202a orange alice 0820321228 $8
```

I want to check if a value in the `description` column contains  a specific substring. For example the first row (adam) has the description of "apple". I want to check to see if the substring "appl" exists in this `description` column.

If so I then want to create a new column named `Data` which would then store the value `need more apples`. If no substring of "appl" is found I dont want to store anything in this column.

This is what the expected new dataframe would look like.

```py
Receipt Description Card Member Account Cost **Data**
200a apple adam 08203928 $2 need more apples
20022a pear bob 08203228 $7
202a orange alice 0820321228 $8
```

Comment: You can use the [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method to test element-wise if a series contains a substring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this:

**Example 1:**

```
df["**Data**"] = df["Description"].map(lambda x: "apple containes" if "appl" in x else '')
```

**Example 2**

If you have mapping of every fruit to check then you could create like this

```
desc = {"appl":"need more apples","pear": "need more pear"}

def check_desc(x):
    for key in desc:
        if key.lower() in x.lower():
            return desc[key]
    return ''

df["**Data**"] = df["Description"].map(lambda x: check_desc(x))
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and more mappings!

Comment: @Jacques  Please upvote If my solution useful to you. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

contains a string and np.where() to check if it contains a string. I do.

```
df['**Data**'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('apple'),'need more apples','')
```