# Creating a new df column based on conditional substring of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanted to create a new column categorizing records according to a substring in a tracking code. For example, it tracking code contains 'KNC-' the new column Channel should be 'Paid Search'

From this post [Pandas: Check if a substring exists in another column then create a new column with a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62567406/pandas-check-if-a-substring-exists-in-another-column-then-create-a-new-column-w)
I was able to find a solution.

```
desc = {"KNC-":"Paid Search","SL-": "Display",'SNP-':'Social','EMC-':'Email'}
def check_desc(x):
    for key in desc:
        if key.lower() in x.lower():
            return desc[key]
    return ''
df['Marketing Channel'] = df["Tracking Code"].map(lambda x: check_desc(x))
```

However, the first thing I tried was using numpy select:

```
conditions = [
    ('KNC-' in df['Tracking Code']),
    ('SL-' in df['Tracking Code']),
    ('SNP-' in df['Tracking Code']),
    ('EMC-' in df['Tracking Code'])
    ]
values = ['Paid Search', 'Display', 'Social', 'Email']
df['Marketing Channel'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

This latter code created the column but all values were zero. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'KNC-' in df['Tracking Code']` checks if the value `KNC-` exists in the column. It doesn't check each value for the substring `KNC-`.

Change your conditions to use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```py
conditions = [
    df['Tracking Code'].str.contains('KNC-'),
    df['Tracking Code'].str.contains('SL-'),
    df['Tracking Code'].str.contains('SNP-'),
    df['Tracking Code'].str.contains('EMC-'),
]
values = ['Paid Search', 'Display', 'Social', 'Email']
df['Marketing Channel'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```