# Pandas sum over rows using conditional substring of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate the sum of several columns based on the column name,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range(start='2021-01-03',end='2021-02-02',freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': dates,
                        'rabbit1_41a': abs(4+0.1*np.random.randn(len(dates))),
                        'rabbit4_100b': abs(5.2+0.5*np.random.randn(len(dates))),
                        'kitten11_445a': abs(0.5+0.1*np.random.randn(len(dates))),
                        'kitten11_72c': abs(0.8+0.5*np.random.randn(len(dates))),
                        'hare2_1000': abs(7+np.random.randn(len(dates))),
                        'hare1_58': abs(8+0.8*np.random.randn(len(dates))),
                        'hare1_26': abs(7.6+0.2*np.random.randn(len(dates))),
                        'hare3_25': abs(9.1+0.3*np.random.randn(len(dates))),
                        }
                  )

# new table, contains sum of rabbit, kitten, hare
df0 = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': dates})

species = ['rabbit', 'kitten', 'hare']

for ii in species:
    for jj in df.columns:
        # calculate sum of rabbit, kitten, hare
##        df0[ii] = df.loc[df[jj][0:int(ii.rindex(ii[-1])+1)]==ii].sum(axis=1)
        df0[ii] = np.select([df[jj].str.contains(ii)]).sum(axis=1)
print(df0.head())
```

The raw data in `df` contains daily measurements and I have a new table `df0` that covers the same time period. I want to calculate the sum of each column, like

```
df0['rabbit'] = df['rabbit1_41a'] + df['rabbit4_100b']     
df0['kitten'] = df['kitten11_445a'] + df['kitten11_72c']
df0['hare'] = df['hare2_1000'] + df['hare1_58'] + df['hare1_26'] + df['hare3_25']
```

How is it done with string slices? This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69320534/3084842) is useful, but I'm not sure how to adapt it to take the **sum** of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only trying to see if the column name contains a substring (as opposed to checking if string data contains a pattern), you could sum over columns that contain a substring.

```
df0["rabbit"] = df[ [ c for c in df.columns if "rabbit" in c ] ].sum( axis = 1 )
```

You could do the same for "kitten" and "hare".

Using your code and starting with `np.random.seed( 123 )`, this would be the top few rows of your output:

```
>>> df0.head()
    date    rabbit    kitten       hare
0 2021-01-03  7.692142  1.920358  33.444147
1 2021-01-04  8.413968  0.999868  31.448853
2 2021-01-05  8.878359  1.957287  32.017930
3 2021-01-06  9.513102  0.838440  33.003162
4 2021-01-07  9.055322  0.622813  31.929664
```

For reference, when you use [pd.Series.str.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) (which can only be used with string values whereas you have numeric columns), you are checking if the data values (and not the column names) contain whatever pattern you input.

Answer (score 0):

If the first 4 characters of the column identify its group uniquely, you can simply do

```
df1 = df.groupby([c[:4] for c in df.columns], axis=1).sum()
```

to get something like

```
    date    hare        kitt        rabb
0   0.0     30.276673   1.076560    9.665169
1   0.0     31.774017   1.445791    10.263471
2   0.0     32.620976   1.627564    8.708358
...
```

which is not quite there yet but close. To beat it into the right shape you could `rename` the columns and `join` with `df['date']]` as the date in `df1` got messed up:

```
species = ['rabbit', 'kitten', 'hare']
sd = {s[:4]:s for s in species}
df[['date']].join(df1.drop(columns = 'date')).rename(columns = sd)
```

output

```
    date         hare       kitten      rabbit
0   2021-01-03  30.276673   1.076560    9.665169
1   2021-01-04  31.774017   1.445791    10.263471
2   2021-01-05  32.620976   1.627564    8.708358
...
```

### Solution 2

Here we do exact matching assuming `species` is given as in your question. Then we groupby on that

```
spnames = [next(s for s in species if s in colname) for colname in df.columns[1:]]
df.set_index('date').groupby(spnames, axis=1).sum()
```

output as required; for reference

```
print(spnames)
['rabbit', 'rabbit', 'kitten', 'kitten', 'hare', 'hare', 'hare', 'hare']
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps

Rename columns stripping the underscore and trailing alphanumeric characters

Step 1 above allows you to melt the columns into elements defined in list

Convert the dataframe from wide to long

Groupby dates and sum. This in my opinion should be the final stage. No need to join to `df0`

```
species = ['rabbit', 'kitten', 'hare']

#Rename df columns to allow use of pd.wide_to_long

df.columns =df.columns.str.replace('\_\w+$','', regex=True)

new=(df0.set_index('date')#Set date as index
      .join(
          pd.wide_to_long(df, species, i="date", j="suffix").droplevel(level=1)#Melt columns into each of the element in the list and sum
          .groupby('date').sum()#Do summation by date
      )
          
      )
```

Comment: will there be problems with `#Rename df columns to allow use of pd.wide_to_long`  if `df` contains many columns? (I've only given a MWE in my question)

Comment: Depends on how you have named your columns. `pd_wide` takes uniformly named columns. In this case I tried make the columns `ColumnNameNumber`  eg `Rabbit6, Hare3, Fox2` It will not take `Rabbit6 Hare_3 Fox2`. In this case it will leave `Hare_3`

Comment: Are you able to print df.columns, paste them and I will advice

Comment: thanks, I don't have uniformly named columns (in my MWE and actual dataset) so I'm looking for something more robust than `pd.wide_to_long`. My `df.columns` has similar format to the MWE

Comment: pd.wide is robust and faster than a for loop obviously. You still can get around it by playing with regex. Create regex pattern `pat=fr"{'|'.join(species)}"` subset date and required columns `s=df.set_index('date').filter(regex=pat, axis=1)` clean columns with elements in list for pd.wide `s.columns=s.columns.str.split('\_').str[0]` and then pd_wide `s=pd.wide_to_long(s.reset_index(), species, i="date", j="suffix").droplevel(level=1).groupby('date').sum()`